# How to see Cycle's material transparency in 3D View

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, 3d-view

I have two planes with the same node setup, but only one of them is transparent in Material Viewport Shading.

[image]

The one that works was created by the Import Images as Planes addon. The other plane was created manually and copying the addon's material setup into a new material.

If I set the addon's material to the "bad" plane it works, so the problem is related to the material itself (nor the object, OPGL or my hardware). I'm working on 2.73.

I have no clue about this behavior, [here is the .blend](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33973) for checking it out.

Comment: I'm going to work in some camera mapping videos soon and having this working is mandatory for checking the camera animation in real time. Importing Image as Planes is not a solution, I need to be able to set up the material myself for every meshes which are going to have the projection.

Comment: @stacker It's weird. I'm on 2.73 too... Just checked on two other PC's. One is AMD but both are NVIDIA.

Comment: sorry I misread the question, I thought viewport shading set to rendered.

Comment: I meant AMD CPU! :P

Comment: @AntonioBuch it does look like a bug. I tried with different image and got the same result: recreating the material I couldn't see transparency. When using import images as planes I could...

Comment: @cegaton So may I report as a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Version 2.76 and after:**

See TimCollinsMedia's answer

**Prior to version 2.76:**

This is highly illogical and probably should not effect the display at all, but the setting that makes those two differ is "Alpha blend" in Blender game engine material settings.

Change the rendering engine to "Blender Game", and change this setting from "opaque" to "Alpha blend" in the material settings, then change back to cycles.

[image]

Comment: How did you figure this out?... very strange indeed

Comment: but he says its cycles

Comment: @Shaiq This is in the viewport (OpenGL), and I guess some obscure OpenGL settings are affecting the way it draws. hjaarnio Nice detective work, +1 :). Perhaps this will be fixed with the upcoming OpenGL overhaul.

Comment: Is it possible to #tag users here since this is likely the guy who will be repairing this issue.  http://blender.stackexchange.com/users/465/psy-fi

Comment: I guess I should have tried it before asking #psy-fi
Let's see if it summons him.

Comment: The other answer works without having to change the render engine. Probably been updated since this post is 2 years old at this point.

Comment: You are correct, this was fixed in 2.76 https://developer.blender.org/T45789, updated the answer

Answer (score 10):

I think I've figured this issue out. I'm in Blender Cycles.

To see the transparency, make sure you're in the "Material" view in your viewport.

[image]

With your image-plane selected, go to the Material tab.

[image]

Toggle down "Settings" at the very bottom. Make sure "Viewport Alpha:" is set to something other than "Opaque". I find "Alpha Clip" and "Alpha Blend" worked well for the .png image I was using.

[image]

Hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: This answer is quite right and it's actually the method I use. Though, at the moment of my question, @hjaarnio 's answer was the correct one. I don't know if I must change the question itself to specify that it is a query concerning to 2.73 version.