# Spotlight Not Illuminating Inside Building

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting

I need to render this scene where the sunlight is entering though the windows and making shadows, I added a spotlight but it seems that the light is only working outside, I have no idea why. My windows have no glass yet.

Of note, I am using 2.79 because of my current hardware.

[image]

[image: I added a glass material to my windows to see if ti would help with the light but this weird circle came up!]

[image: Materials]

The weird circle you see in the windows is that i accidentaly duplicated the glass, i deleted the duplicated faces and correct the normals and now everything is looking goood

Comment: the problem is your window material and the fact that it isnt transparent. Are you using alpha blend for the window material? I would also suggest rendering at those specific angles for your screenshots instead of just screenshotting a graining un-rendered preview.

Comment: you should include screenshots of your settings or link your blend file so we can check it out

Comment: it may have to do with light through glass? maybe the solution is to create a emissive plane or an area light at the windows position?

Comment: @object Hi, the windows has no material and no glass either. i was following a tutorial and the guy was doing it on blender 2.9 , he simple added a wall with holes and then the light, volume etc... aand the light was perfect and casting all the shadows of the windows's frame. i will try adding the glass mesh  to the windows to see

Comment: @Chris one thing i found out so far is that selecting the "non color data" inside the image texture node enlightens the wall when i choose sunlight

Comment: if you provide your blend file - i will help you

Comment: It looks like perhaps you've got a default world light on the exterior, but then there is some faint light coming through the windows - presumably from your spot lamp. Have you tried to increased the power (watts) on your spot lamp? Or perhaps try a sun lamp... as other commenters have said some screenshots of your light settings, setup or blend file would go a long way here. Hope you work it out.

Comment: @Chris i added to the post but i dont know how to pack the texture and everything into the file

Comment: @Aubrey hello, i added new sscreenshot and blendfiles and i am sorry for not doing this before

Comment: @wnr: your link does not work. To include  all into blend file use file -> external data -> pack all into blend file, then save, then use this link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: @Chris Hi Chris it is working now, i packed eveything. thank you for the info!

Comment: thank you. now the answer was easy :)

Comment: @Chris Thank you so very much! it looks so beautiful now ! :) but i jjust cant find the (blend mode and shadow mode) what section is it located? i am on 2.79 version,

Comment: i have no idea. my first blender version was 2.92 when i started with blender :(

Comment: i asked a new question for that https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219533/how-can-i-change-the-blend-mode-to-alpha-in-2-79

Comment: @Chris Thanks a lot!!! :)!

Comment: please checkout his comments here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219533/how-can-i-change-the-blend-mode-to-alpha-in-2-79?noredirect=1#comment370594_219533

Comment: @Chris yes i am reading these now. When i saw the blend mode and shadow mode i remembered seen it somewhere before, as i am trying to render in cycles i was looking for it there but it couldnt be , it makes sense that it is in game engine and internal render mode on 2.79 but i had no idea as i couldnt remember

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. change spot strength to 1000
2. change glass material to : [image]
3. and most important change these: (blend mode and shadow mode)

[image]

4. and you will get :

[image]

to change blend mode in 2.79 checkout these answers:

[Material Opacity in viewport?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/material-opacity-in-viewport)

[How to see Cycle's material transparency in 3D View](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23714/how-to-see-cycles-material-transparency-in-3d-view)