# how can i change the blend mode to alpha in 2.79

Tags: blend-modes

In Eevee in newer versions you have to change blend mode to Alpha blend if you want to use transparency.

How do you change this blend mode in former version before 2.8? So how can i do this in 2.79 with Blender Render engine? (thanks Jachym)

Comment: Hello :). Since Blender 2.79 doesn't include Eevee, are you asking about the Blender Render engine? :)

Comment: ooppps, sorry for my "not knowing" - i started learning Blender with 2.92 :( ...and....yes, i must have meant this! ;D

Comment: And for Cycles: [How to see Cycle's material transparency in 3D View](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23714/78972)

Comment: thank you!!!!!!